# How to merge the array value into single array based on group

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i m looking for a way to merge multiple array value into single array based on the application group. Is there someone who can help me with this problem?

My Array:

```
Array{
         [0]=>Application{
          [id]=>1
          [name]=>facebook
          [group]=>mobile_app
         }
         [1]=>Application{
          [id]=>2
          [name]=>youtube
          [group]=>mobile_app
         }
         [2]=>Application{
           [id]=>3
           [name]=>whatsapp
           [group]=>messenger
         }
         [3]=>Application{
           [id]=>4
           [name]=>skype
           [group]=>messenger
         }
     }
```

Requested output:

```
Array{
[0]=>application{
[id]=>1
[app_name_1]=>facebook
[app_name_2]=>youtube
[group]=>mobile_app
}
[1]=>application{
[id]=>2
[app_name_1]=>whatsapp
[app_name_2]=>skype
[group]=>messenger
}
}
```

Comment: In the requsted output `[id]=>1` what is for?

Comment: Could you please explain a bid for me, because I find it hard to understand how you want it filtered.
You are putting youtube under mobile_app and messenger, but the group on youtube is mobile_app, is this an exception for youtube then?

Comment: @uroloke sorry for the error is suppose to skype and not youtube. I edit the error already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume:

`$array` is equal to:

```
Array{
         [0]=>Application{
          [id]=>1
          [name]=>facebook
          [group]=>mobile_app
         }
         [1]=>Application{
          [id]=>2
          [name]=>youtube
          [group]=>mobile_app
         }
         [2]=>Application{
           [id]=>3
           [name]=>whatsapp
           [group]=>messenger
         }
         [3]=>Application{
           [id]=>4
           [name]=>skype
           [group]=>messenger
         }
     }
```

So, for the first array, each element in the array is an instance of the Application Object which should like this:

```
class Application {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $group;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $group) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->group = $group;
    }
}
```

And, a few instances of that object make up the array `$array`

To format it the way you want, you have to first sort them like this:

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    $newAppName = $element->name;
    $newArray[$element->group][] = $element->name;
}
```

And to store objects of them, you need to design a new class like this:

```
class ApplicationObjectTwo {
    public $id;
    public $group;

    public function __construct($id, $group) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->group = $group;
    }
}
```

And once you do that, you want to create instances of the object and store them in the array like this:

```
$counter = 1;
$counterTwo = 1;
$otherArray = [];

foreach($newArray as $group => $data) {
    $otherArray[] = new ApplicationObjectTwo($counter, $group);
    foreach($data as $app) {
        $varName = "app_name_" . $counterTwo;
        $index = $counter - 1;
        $otherArray[$index]->$varName = $app;
        $counterTwo++;
    }

    $counter++;
    $counterTwo = 1;
}
```

And once you do that, you want to `print_r($otherArray)`

Pastebin for the entire code: http://pastebin.com/S07BMBuV

Answer (score 1):

As I was unsure exactly what you asked for because of `youtube` being under `mobile and`messenger`, I just assumed that was a typo. <br>
I have made this example for you`br>

We start off by creating your array and the array you are going to filter into.

```
$array = array(
    array(
       "id" => 1,
       "name" => "facebook",
       "group" => "mobile"
   ),
   array(
      "id" => 2,
      "name" => "youtube",
      "group" => "mobile"
   ),
   array(
      "id" => 3,
      "name" => "whatsapp",
      "group" => "messenger"
   ),
   array(
      "id" => 4,
      "name" => "skype",
      "group" => "messenger"
   )
);
$req_array = array(
   "mobile" => array(
   ),
   "messenger" => array(
   )
);
```

Then we loop through all our sub arrays in our `$array` variable. 
Here we take out the group name and group app name and then we push the name into the group in `$our` req_array.

```
foreach($array as $app){
   $group = $app["group"];
   $name = $app["name"];
   array_push($req_array[$group], $name);
}
```

Comment: @HassanAlthaf, Why do you not think it is close to what he want's?

Comment: Thanks @uruloke is close enough but i prefer is the group value stays in the array

Comment: @uruloke He wants something completely different. Firstly, his array is not full of arrays, his array is a collection of `Application` objects.